# Bootstrap Navbar Collapsible menu in Mobile View Needs Different hover and active colors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

HOVER AND FOCUS EFFECT NOT WORKING FOR MOBILE VIEW

I am facing problems in selecting the hover color and a class kept active in navbar's collapsible menu. I need a hover effect with black color in mobile view and a different one in desktop view.

My desktop view is well and good, I just need to change the hover effect and active effect for the mobile view.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar-custom {
    margin-top: -40px !important;
    z-index: -1;
}
ul.nav.navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
}
.collapsing,
.in {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    text-align: center;
}
.collapsing ul>li>a,
.in ul>li>a {
    color: #FFFFFF!important;
    text-shadow: #FFFFFF 0px 0px 0.5px!important;
}
  
.navbar-collapse>.navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-collapse>.navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-collapse>.navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black!important;
    text-shadow: black 0px 0px 0.5px!important;
}
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar  navbar-custom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Teachers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Tried a dozen of things to my knowledge and reach and then came here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I did solve the problem, the issue was created because of the " z-index".
Actually, not only the hover effect but the entire menu was not working in mobile view, it was only displayed.

Previously I had used z-index to hide the elements extra margin in the mobile view and this caused another layer to overlay it, causing the menu dysfunction.

I am attaching my updated CSS media query here

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 736px) {
    .navbar-custom {
        min-height: 0px;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    .collapsing,
    .in {
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .collapsing ul>li>a,
    .in ul>li>a {
        color: #FFFFFF!important;
        text-shadow: #FFFFFF 0px 0px 0.2px!important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse>.navbar-nav>.active>a,
    .navbar-collapse>.navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
    .navbar-collapse>.navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: black!important;
        text-shadow: black 0px 0px 0.2px!important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse>.navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
    .navbar-collapse>.navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: black !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope this helps other users, the important point is : The navbar in mobile view was overlayed by another layer.

Answer (score 1):

**you must write your code inside that for mobile**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   /* media screen styles*/
}
```

Comment: Mr. Serken , Bootstrap changes the the navbar into collapsible form from about 767px, so its written over here as @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {    }